# Bamboo shell script gets stuck on Ubuntu server deployment

Tags: shell, bamboo

We have a shell script through which we are deploying updated repos and then we are restarting the apps on the server .
Earlier we were using Linux server and now we have migrated to Ubuntu server.

On new Ubuntu server when we run the deployment it works fine on the host I can see deployment is done apps are restarted but the bamboo deployment page shows deploying

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -e

USER="app"
LOG_DIR="/logs/$USER"

cd /my/dir/groupctl
echo "---------------------------------" >> $LOG_DIR/bamboo.log
date >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
echo "Starting ${bamboo.REPO_NAME} apps" >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
./apps --restart >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
echo "Restart completed for ${bamboo.REPO_NAME}" >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
echo "" >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
echo "Status ${bamboo.REPO_NAME} apps" >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
./apps --status >> $LOG_DIR/bambool.log
```

On the Ubuntu box these task are completed and logs are also updated but not sure why on Bamboo it is still running . And this happening only on Ubuntu on Linux box everything is fine

Comment: At which command is it hanging?

Comment: @user1934428 all commands are successful I can see in the logs apps are getting started and status command also executed .

Comment: So, all commands terminate happily, but the bamboo job still doesn't? In this case, I don't think you can do anything in your script; it looks like related to bamboo, and I suggest that you ask this at [su].